# Background not expanding to the viewport width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to extend the width of the background to that of the viewport and its height equal to the content I'm putting inside it. As you can see, I've set the width of .bgcont in CSS to 100vw and height: 100% but it's still not extending to it. Please also help with the height. I want the background's height to end just below the 2 buttons I've added.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
nav h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;

}
header .bgcont{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);

    /*z-index: 6;*/
    border-bottom-left-radius: 300% 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 300% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100% ;

}

nav{
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 1rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 0.75rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav h1{
        font-size: large;
    }
}
.signin{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #1ecec2;
}
.content h1{
    color: white;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding-top: 2em;

}
.content p{
    color: white;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.intro {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4970f1;
}
.play{
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.play, .intro{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container bgcont" >
            <nav class="d-flex flex-row">
                <h1 class="sling mb-0"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
                <ul class="mb-0">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
            </nav>
            <div class="container d-flex flex-column text-center align-items-center content">
                <h1>Discover Great Apps, Games Extension Plugin App Showcase</h1>
                <p>Surprisingly, there is a very vocal faction of the design community that
                    wants to see filler text banished the original sources from who it comes.</p>
                <div class="container d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <button type="button" class="intro">How we do it</button>
                    <button type="button" class="play">Play into video</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Width issue

For the width issue, it's just a matter of adding the following:

```css
header .bgcont {
  …
  max-width: none;
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that this line is overriding rules inside of `_grid.scss` for various breakpoints:

### Height issue

For the height to end just below the two buttons you've added, remove the `height` rule in `.bg-cont`. To give things a bit of breathing room, I added a touch of bottom padding as well.

**Demo**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
nav h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;

}
header .bgcont{
    max-width: none; /* Overrides existing rules defined in _grid.scss */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);

    /*z-index: 6;*/
    border-bottom-left-radius: 300% 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 300% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em; /* <-- Added to make things look nice */
    /* height: 100% /*     /* <-- Removed this */ 
}

nav{
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 1rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 0.75rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav h1{
        font-size: large;
    }
}
.signin{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #1ecec2;
}
.content h1{
    color: white;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding-top: 2em;

}
.content p{
    color: white;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.intro {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4970f1;
}
.play{
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.play, .intro{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container bgcont" >
            <nav class="d-flex flex-row">
                <h1 class="sling mb-0"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
                <ul class="mb-0">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
            </nav>
            <div class="container d-flex flex-column text-center align-items-center content">
                <h1>Discover Great Apps, Games Extension Plugin App Showcase</h1>
                <p>Surprisingly, there is a very vocal faction of the design community that
                    wants to see filler text banished the original sources from who it comes.</p>
                <div class="container d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <button type="button" class="intro">How we do it</button>
                    <button type="button" class="play">Play into video</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, but how do I fix the issue of the height?

Comment: @TalhaMunir Just remove the `height: 100%` from `.bg-cont`. Please see the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bootstrap related issue. Actually you are using `container` class which is meant for fixed width grid.

You suppose to use `container-fluid` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `min-height` instead of `height` to include the button on small screens and remove container class to have full width:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* don't need this
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
*/
header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
nav h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;

}
header .bgcont{
    background-image:linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);

    /*z-index: 6;*/
    border-bottom-left-radius: 300% 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 300% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /*don't use vw to avoid including scrollbar in the width*/
    min-height: 100% ;
    padding-bottom:50px;

}

nav{
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 1rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 0.75rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav h1{
        font-size: large;
    }
}
.signin{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #1ecec2;
}
.content h1{
    color: white;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding-top: 2em;

}
.content p{
    color: white;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.intro {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4970f1;
}
.play{
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.play, .intro{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="bgcont px-2" > <!-- used px to add some padding like done by container -->
            <nav class="d-flex flex-row">
                <h1 class="sling mb-0"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
                <ul class="mb-0">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
            </nav>
            <div class="container d-flex flex-column text-center align-items-center content">
                <h1>Discover Great Apps, Games Extension Plugin App Showcase</h1>
                <p>Surprisingly, there is a very vocal faction of the design community that
                    wants to see filler text banished the original sources from who it comes.</p>
                <div class="container d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <button type="button" class="intro">How we do it</button>
                    <button type="button" class="play">Play into video</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also optimize your code and rely on Bootstrap classes. I have also used gradient to have a better curve at the bottom:

```css
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header a{
    color: white;

}
nav h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;

}
header .bgcont{
    background:
      radial-gradient(55% 100px at top,transparent 93%,#fff 95%) bottom/100% 100px no-repeat,
      linear-gradient( -47deg, rgb(56,97,234) 0%, rgb(102,137,255) 100%);
    padding-bottom:30px;

}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 1rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav ul li a{
        padding: 0.75rem 0;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav h1{
        font-size: large;
    }
}
.signin{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #1ecec2;
}
.content h1{
    color: white;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding-top: 2em;

}
.content p{
    color: white;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.intro {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4970f1;
}
.play{
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.play, .intro{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="bgcont px-2 pt-1 min-vh-100" > 
            <nav class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h1 class="sling mb-0"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
                <ul class="mb-0 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
            </nav>
            <div class="container d-flex flex-column text-center align-items-center content">
                <h1>Discover Great Apps, Games Extension Plugin App Showcase</h1>
                <p>Surprisingly, there is a very vocal faction of the design community that
                    wants to see filler text banished the original sources from who it comes.</p>
                <div class="container d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <button type="button" class="intro">How we do it</button>
                    <button type="button" class="play">Play into video</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the bg in the container, width: 1140px. For this reason it is not covering the full area. and for the height, in fullscreen view the height is covering 100% of the viewport.

[Refer to the screenshot](https://snag.gy/bSgETC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Class `container` it's used for a web with a max width.
Class `container-fluid` it's for web that uses full width.

When using `container` it's supposed you will change `max-width` to set what your design has