# Adjusting image in viewport

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to set the background image to 50vh and have this curve at the bottom. 
However, when I do so, it crops up the image from the bottom and the curve is lost.
How do I go about it that curve may retain even after setting it to 50vh?

[image]

```css
.background{
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45nE.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    /*height: 916px;*/ /*this is the height of the image*/
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center background">

        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: you can simply do this multiple background like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55195257/8620333 (answer of your old question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `background-size` and `background-position` properties too:

```css
.background{
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45nE.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;    
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    /*height: 916px;*/ /*this is the height of the image*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center background">

        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can edit it according to your demand.this javascript function will fulfill your required task

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 100, 200, 100, 200, 20);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the background position and size like this:

```css
.background{
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r45nE.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    /*height: 916px;*/ /*this is the height of the image*/
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center background">

        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using as `background` by which image is there but your are viewing only its upper half part. You need to move background in your view port.

```
background-position: bottom;
background-size: cover;
```

Positon will show your image from bottom and background-size will cover your image in viewport.